# OpenID no end point found error

Tags: support, error-message, login, myopenid

I am using OpenID ([MyOpenID](http://myopenid.com/)) to login to Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange websites. But sometimes, I get an error message saying:

> Unable to login with your OpenID provider: No OpenID endpoint found.". Below is the screenshot.

What causes this error?

[image]

Comment: What does http://test-id.org/OP/Sreg.aspx report?

Comment: Same for me, test-id.org gives the same error: Login failed: No OpenID endpoint found. https://www.myopenid.com is slow and sometimes unresponsive.. maybe a problem on their end?

Comment: Only sometimes I get the error. Next time when it fails, I will test it. This time it loads myopenid.com.

Comment: It finally let me in.. seems to be intermittent.

Comment: same here - it doesn't work the whole day for me - definitely on their end I'd say

Comment: Now I get Login failed: No OpenID endpoint found after testing with http://myopenid.com/ for http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate. I think the problem is with their website.

Comment: In future, [use this link](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/www.myopenid.com)

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem on the MyOpenID end of things. They seem to be getting progressively worse.

[We recommend you add another OpenID provider to your account and login with them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131965/unable-to-log-in-using-myopenid-com/131969#131969)... Accordingly, we've demoted MyOpenID from being a recommended provider.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error - you must use https://www.myopenid.com/. This worked for me :-)